# Unresolved import 'util'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Extensive searching on Google, Reddit, and this site was fruitless, so hopefully someone here can help me out. The code

```
import util
```

gives the error `unresolved import 'util'`. `util.py` is a module in the same folder. For reference, here is my hierarchy:

```
\Projects
    |-\adventure
        |-\src
            |-__init__.py
            |-main.py
            |-util.py
```

and this is my VSCode's info:

```
Version: 1.32.2 (user setup)
Commit: e64cb27b1a0cbbc3f643c9fc6c7d93d6c6509951
Date: 2019-03-13T02:00:46.035Z
Electron: 3.1.6
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `from adventure import util`?

Comment: `from adventure.src import util`? :)

Comment: `import .util` most likely.

Comment: Those all then get the `unresolved import` error, unfortunately.

Comment: "unresolved import" isn't a Python error. What's throwing that error?

Comment: which file is the `import util` in?

Comment: @AdamSmith I'm using pep8 for linting, so either that or VSCode. My money would be on the former, though.

Comment: @KomronAripov `main.py`

Comment: try running it as a module: `python3 -m main` or if you are inside the the "adventure" folder, as `python3 -m src.main`

Comment: @KomronAripov That didn't resolve the issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I believe is happening is that VSCode is running the `main.py` from a current working directory that is not `/Projects` or any of its sub directories. So when you try to `import util` or `from adventure import util`, it cannot find the file. A quick and easy fix would be to append the path to `/src` to the `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Projects/adventure/src')
import util
```

or whatever the *absolute path* to `/src` may be. A bit cleaner might be to append your `/Projects` directory, and then import from adventure, so that you don't have to append extra directories if you want to include modules from other packages in your Projects folder.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Projects') # whatever the absolute path to /Projects is
from adventure import util
```

---

Another possibility involves updating the VSCode configuration file to specify a modified `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, to specify the path to import the project from. You can either include the following in the `launch.json` under your configuration:

```
"env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "/path/to/src/:${PYTHONPATH}"
}
```

or create an `.env` file to specify the same:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/src/:${PYTHONPATH}
```

These were obtained from the [visualstudio docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file). Note that you may have to change `:` to `;` and `/` to `\\` on windows.

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately. Could it have something to do with the location of `python.exe`? I installed it into my `/Documents` folder, and the `/Projects` folder is located inside the same folder as all of the installation files (`/Python`).

Comment: @DCoded it shouldn't really. I do have another idea though- I'll update my post

Comment: @DCoded just to be sure, you did write your absolute path using `\\ instead of /` in the first attempt right? Since you're on windows, you're path delimiters are double backslashes.

Comment: @DCoded could you try running the code on commandline without use of the VSCode, just to narrow it down a bit? Open `cmd`, navigate to your `main.py`, run `Path/To/Python/python.exe main.py` and see if it gives the same error?

Comment: Creating the `.env` file with the `PYTHONPATH` specified seems to have worked, although I didn't include the `:${PYTHONPATH}` at the end. Thank you.